# How to query a Django JSONField with a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, django, jsonfield

I'm using Django 3.2.3 / Python 3.7.8 / PostgreSQL 12.3

models.py

```
class Booking(models.Model):
    reference = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)
    services = models.JSONField()
```

The `services` structure is:

```
{
'1':{
    'id': 3,
    'name': 'Name 1'
    },
'2':{
    'id': 4,
    'name': 'Name 2
    },
'3':{
    'id': 3,
    'name': 'Name 3
    },
 ...
}
```

How to filter the `Booking` with `services` having `id` `3`?

I tried `Booking.objects.filter(services__contains=[{'id': 3}])` but couldn't get through.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try `is_null` look up.

Rather than `contains`, as follow:

```
Booking.objects.filter(services__3__isnull=False)
```

Also I recommend you to see the django JSON queryset documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#querying-jsonfield)